# query observable and angularfire2

Tags: firebase, angular

i'm wondering how can i use angularfire2 to query data an get the list of the queried data and then observer next the data to be able to subscribe to it and pass it into an ngFor loop, for example , how can i transform this sample code below to use angularfire2

```
load() {
  const messagesObservable = new BehaviorSubject<MessageThread[]>(null)
  this.rootRef.child("users").child(this.currentUserid).child("rooms").on("child_added", snapshot => {
    key = snapshot.key()
    this.rootRef.child("messages").orderByKey().equalTo(key).on("value", snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      const Messages = Object.keys(data).map(id => new MessageThread(id))
      MessageThread.next(Messages)
    })
  })
  return Messages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
}

load() {
  return this.af.list(this.rootRef.child("messages")
                   .orderByKey().equalTo(key));
}
```

Comment: i was doin this but when i was loading the data, i was getting a white screen